# XML: define variable in an optimal way

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

From same input I have different *xpaths* for the same element (its almost exactly the same path except for 1 element, see below)

My logic its depends on the element "typology" (defined on my code)

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:variable name="date">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$typology='A' or $typology='B' ">
<xsl:value-of select="/Header/info/data/Body/basketAB/date"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$typology='C' or $typology='D' or $typology='E'">
<xsl:value-of select="/Header/info/data/Body/basketCDE/date"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="'CheckPath'"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

How can I avoid to use choose +several paths and get "date" **just** from 1 path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it defining **date** as:

```
<xsl:variable name="date" select="//date"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the descendant axis and use a more explicit path:

```
<xsl:variable name="date" select="/Header/info/data/Body/*/date"/>
```

This is assuming that the input cannot contain both `basketAB` and `basketCDE` elements (this point is not clear from your question, but otherwise neither this nor the currently accepted answer can work).

---

If the above assumption turns out to be incorrect, you could do:

```
<xsl:variable name="date" select="/Header/info/data/Body/*[contains(name(), $typology)]/date"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this single XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
concat(/Header/info/data/Body/basketAB
                               [contains('|A|B|', concat('|', $typology, '|'))]/date
     | /Header/info/data/Body/basketCDE
                              [contains('|C|D|E|', concat('|', $typology, '|'))]/date,
       substring('CheckPath', 
                 1 div not(contains('|A|B|C|D|E|', concat('|', $typology, '|'))))
      )
```

**Verification using XSLT 1.0**:

Given this source XML document:

```
<Header>
  <info>
    <data>
        <Body>
          <basketAB>
             <date>date1</date>
          </basketAB>
          <basketCDE>
             <date>date2</date>
          </basketCDE>
        </Body>
    </data>
  </info>
</Header>
```

**this XSLT transformation evaluates the above XPath expression** and outputs the result of this evaluation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:variable name="typology" select="'A'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="date" select=
      "concat(/Header/info/data/Body/basketAB[contains('|A|B|', concat('|', $typology, '|'))]/date
            | /Header/info/data/Body/basketCDE[contains('|C|D|E|', concat('|', $typology, '|'))]/date,
              substring('CheckPath', 1 div not(contains('|A|B|C|D|E|', concat('|', $typology, '|'))))
              )"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Run the transformation several times**, each time specifying a different value for the variable `$typology`:

**The wanted results are produced in all cases**:

'A'  --> date1

'B'  --> date1

---

'C'  --> date2

'D'  --> date2

'E'  --> date2

---

'X' --> CheckPath